# how to check a checkbox on the check of one checkbox in asp.net?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-controls

i have two checkboxes.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkPODPrice" Text="Enable POD" runat="server" OnClick="JavaScript:EnableDisable(this);"/>

<asp:CheckBox ID="chckPurchaseEnabel" Text="Enable Buy" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

if 1st text box is checked , i need to check the other one too and i am doing this on click function but its not working. Help me out.

javascript function is

```
function EnableDisable(obj) {

    if (obj.checked) {

        $("#chckPurchaseEnabel").checked = true;
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the attribute as below.

```
$("#chckPurchaseEnabel").attr('checked', true);
```

Example Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x1aw734b/